# Can RANSAC be improved to remove outliers?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection, ransac

I am using SIFT feature detector and descriptor. I am matching the points between two images. I am using `findHomography()` function of OpenCV with the RANSAC method.

When I read about the RANSAC algorithm, it is said that adjusting a threshold parameter for RANSAC can improve the results. But I don't want to hardcode any parameter.

I know RANSAC is removing outliers in matches. Can anyone let me know if removing outliers (not all of them) with basic methods before applying homography improves the result of homography?

If so, how can we apply an operation before RANSAC to remove outliers?

Comment: The RANSAC method estimates the homography you want by discarding outliers. The method operates based on the assumption, that most of your samples are in line with the underlying homography. Noise in the data is eliminated and the parameter is just there to give you flexibility if the model is not 100% accurate. So prefiltering will not help if the model is inaccurate (e.g. because you have major distortions), only adjusting the threshold will.

Comment: I have to remind you that if you use `findHomography()`, you have made an assumption that all the 3D points in world coordinate are in a planar surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your definition of a good result? RANSAC is about a tradeoff between the number of points and their precision, so there is no uniform definition of good: you have more inliers if their accuracy is worse and vice versa.

The parameter you are talking about is probably an outlier threshold and it may be just badly tuned so you have too many approximate inliers or too few super accurate inliers. Now, if you pre-filter your outliers you will just speed up your RANSAC but unlikely to improve the solution. Eventually the speed of RANSAC with Homography boils down to the probability of selecting 4 inliers and when their proportion is higher the convergence is more speedy.

The other methods to sort out outliers before applying RANSAC is to look at simpler constraints such as ordering of points, straight lines still being straight lines, [cross-ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) and other invariants of Homography transformation. Finally you may want to use higher level features such as lines to calculate homography. Note, that in homogeneous coordinates when points are transformed as p2=H*p1, the lines are transformed as l2 = H<sup>-t</sup> * l1. This can actually increase the accuracy (since lines are macro features and are less noisy than point of interests) while straight lines can be detected via a Hough transform.

Comment: A thing I forgot to mention - RANSAC as an iterative method has to find homography many times and thus runs a cheap algorithm (e.g. DLT). To find a true homography you have to treat the output of RANSAC as an initialization point for a non-linear algorithm (e.g. LM). The difference between the cheap and non-linear algorithm is in the optimization metrics. The non-linear one optimizes the right metrics (sum of squared point distances) but pays the price for this (it is slow). A cheap algorithm is fast but optimizes the wrong metrics (error in parameters).

Answer (score 1):

No, the whole point of RANSAC and related algorithms is to remove outliers.

However, it is possible to refine the algorithm in ways that avoid the definition of somewhat arbitrary threshold.

A good starting point is Torr's old [MLESAC paper](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2000/Torr00/torr00.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your update. Can you please add it to accepted answer for information to future readers at it is also holding an good answer.